Default multi-touch gestures on Ubuntu 22.04 are gone
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a Dell Inspiron 16 Plus laptop. Originally, I could use my touch with 3-finger left/right to switch between workspaces. However, today I can no longer do that.
I am thinking I might accidentally change some configuration files so it change the default setting. Do someone know where I could change it back?
Thank you!
(I am hoping not to install any other extension.)
